# How to use tags input of bootstrap with textarea

Tags: textarea, bootstrap-tags-input

How to use tags-input of bootstrap with textarea? I have applied `data-role="tagsinput"` against the textarea. But tags-input is not working whereas same code is working for `input type="text"`.

Answer (score 1):

Support is not provided for the Textarea element. It is better to use the Input element for the Taginputs.

See here for reference:
https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/38

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Apologies @Ethaan I am new to here.