# How to use tags input of bootstrap with textarea tag (data-role="tagsinput")

Tags: javascript, html, tags, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-tags-input

```html
 <textarea id="Box" class="tags form-control" placeholder="X Axis values"></textarea>
```

i want show user selected options in text box area in tag wise with remove option.

How to use tags-input of bootstrap with textarea? I have applied data-role="tagsinput". But tags-input is not working. as we know, we have the same issue in Stackoverflow. but for that no solution.

need solution/hint for this  [How to use tags input of bootstrap with textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922454/how-to-use-tags-input-of-bootstrap-with-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap tags-input `does not work with textarea`. Support is not provided.

However you can use it with `input type="text"` and apply the following css to make it work like textarea.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
min-height: 100px;
}
```

[See this link](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/38)

Comment: i have updated the link check it............https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/38

Comment: Won't make it look like a text area. It only increases the height and the cursor is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

try this css on input text for scroll on Input Like textarea

```
.tags-input {
      max-width: 100%;
      line-height: 22px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      height: 65px;
      cursor: text;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this step

```
<style>
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    line-height: 15px !important;
    min-height: 165px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px
}

span.tag.label {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 5px;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}
<style/>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputtags" data-role="tagsinput" name="keywords">
```